# Making an API Call to SWAPI using asyncFetch

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to make an api call and I keep getting the error message in my console. I have been banging my head against my desk all day. If anyone can give me some feedback on how to make this work, I would be so grateful. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHr5k.png)

```js
const results = document.querySelector("#results");

async function asyncFetch(value) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/${value}/`);
  const data = await res.json();
  displayResults(data, value);
}

function displayResults(data, value) {
    let output = "";
    if (value === 'films') {
        data.results.forEach(item => {
            output += `
                <div class="card p-3 m-3" style="opacity:.8">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-center">${item.title}</h4>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">Producer</span>: ${item.producer}<br>
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">Director</span>: ${item.director}<br>
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">Release Date</span>: ${item.release_date}<br>
                        <p class=""text-center>${item.opening_crawl}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `
        })
    }
    if (value === 'people') {
        data.results.forEach(item => {
            output += `
                <div class="card p-3 m-3" style="opacity:.8">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-center">${item.name}</h4>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">Height</span>: ${item.height}<br>
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">Birth Year</span>: ${item.birth_year}<br>
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">Skin Color</span>: ${item.skin_color}<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `
        })
    }
    if (value === 'vehicles') {
        data.results.forEach(item => {
            output += `
                <div class="card p-3 m-3" style="opacity:.8">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-center">${item.name}</h4>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">Capacity</span>: ${item.cargo_capacity} kg<br>
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">Model</span>: ${item.model}<br>
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">manufacturer</span>: ${item.manufacturer}<br>
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline">Vehicle Class</span>: ${item.vehicle_class}<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `
        })
    }
    results.innerHTML = output;
}

// event listener for buttons
document.querySelector("#buttons").addEventListener("click", e => {
  asyncFetch(e.target.textContent.trim().toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `const data = await res.json()` you are telling `fetch` to expect a `JSON` response from `https://swapi.co/api/${value}/`.

But this URL is actually returning an HTML page. (Which starts with `<`). `fetch` can't parse it as JSON, thus says `invalid <` in JSON.

You need to make sure the URL actually sends a valid JSON response.

Comment: Hi Nadir, thank you for the feedback. I'm still having a hard time following how to fix this code. Could you possibly share a snippet of what you are referring to?

Comment: The API you are making the request to is sending HTML data, while `fetch` is expecting `JSON` data. The problem is not with the code, but with URL you are using.

Comment: Could you give the full API URL for `https://swapi.co/api/${value}/`?

Comment: I was able to figure it out... I was using the old .co and not .dev

Comment: Thank you again for your help